# `cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:37541` when using undetected-chromedriver with Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

After using Selenium, I decided to try `undetected-chromedriver` so I installed it using

```
 pip install undetected-chromedriver
```

However, running this simple script

```
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc

options = uc.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
with driver:
    driver.get('https://google.com')
```

gives the error

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:37541
> from chrome not reachable

There's no issue using regular Selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox"); # Bypass OS security model

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
with driver:
    driver.get('https://google.com')
```

Here's the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/test-bot/src/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    driver = uc.Chrome()
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.9/site-packages/undetected_chromedriver/v2.py", line 302, in __init__
    super(Chrome, self).__init__(
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 93, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 248, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.9/site-packages/undetected_chromedriver/v2.py", line 577, in start_session
    super(Chrome, self).start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 339, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 400, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 236, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:52681
from chrome not reachable
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578700 (2f1ed5f9343c13f73144538f15c00b370eda6706),platform=Linux 5.11.0-18-generic x86_64)
```

Any suggestions?

---

### Attempt #1

Also tried setting the `executable_path` to `/usr/bin/chromedriver`

```
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc

options = uc.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--no-first-run --no-service-autorun --password-store=basic')

CHROME_DRIVER_PATH = '/usr/bin/chromedriver'
driver = uc.Chrome(executable_path=CHROME_DRIVER_PATH, options=options)
with driver:
    driver.get('https://google.com')
```

which gives the same error

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:42305
> from chrome not reachable

Checked that the path does exists

```
# ll /usr/bin/chromedriver
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 8298464 Oct  1 14:19 /usr/bin/chromedriver*
```

---

### Attempt #2

Tried using Xvfb and disabling headless mode

```
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc
from xvfbwrapper import Xvfb
vdisplay = Xvfb(width=800, height=1280)
vdisplay.start()

options = uc.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--no-first-run --no-service-autorun --password-store=basic')
options.user_data_dir = f'./tmp/test_undetected_chromedriver'
options.add_argument(f'--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument(f'--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument(f'--disable-dev-shm-usage')

CHROME_DRIVER_PATH = '/usr/bin/chromedriver'
driver = uc.Chrome(executable_path=CHROME_DRIVER_PATH, options=options, headless=False)
with driver:
    driver.get('https://google.com') 
    print(driver.title)
```

slightly different error

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:42467
> from unknown error: unable to discover open pages
> (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578700 (2f1ed5f9343c13f73144538f15c00b370eda6706),platform=Linux 5.11.0-18-generic x86_64)

Comment: Try to [set up logging](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/logging) for your driver and find a clue there.

Answer (score 8):

I had the exact same issue in Centos 7 and the problem was the versions of chrome, undetected-chrome and chromedriver where NOT aligned.

Solution that worked for me (I'm using Python v3.8):

1. Remove the existing versions

> ```
> cd /YOUR_CHROMEDRIVER_PATH
> yum remove google-chrome*
> python3.8 -m pip uninstall undetected-chromedriver
> rm -f chromedriver
> ```

2. Install aligned versions

> ```
> python3.8 -m pip install undetected-chromedriver==3.0.6
> wget -N http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/96.0.4664.35/chromedriver_linux64.zip
> unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
> yum -y install https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/x86_64/google-chrome-stable-96.0.4664.110-1.x86_64.rpm
> ln -s /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable /bin/chrome
> ```

3. Example of my working python script:

> ```
> import undetected_chromedriver as uc
> from selenium import webdriver
>
> chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
> chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
> chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
> chrome_options.add_argument('--enable-javascript')
> chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
> user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.0 Safari/605.1.15'
> chrome_options.add_argument('User-Agent={0}'.format(user_agent))
> chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
> chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', True)
>
> driver = uc.Chrome(executable_path='/path_to_your_driver/chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options,service_args=['--quiet'])
> driver.implicitly_wait(6.5)
>
> driver.get("https://google.com")
> ```

Hope this helps someone, as I wasted several days to find this solution!! :-)

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to install chromedriver when undetected downloads and patches chromedriver for you. However, even after doing that, this didn't work for me. Granted, I do have Google Chrome 108.0.5359.98 installed but according to your link, the closest matching chromedriver is only 108.0.5359.71.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. How did you work out which version of chromedriver and chrome itself you need? I'm trying to run it on Mac Os and I'm getting the same errors.

Answer (score 2):

remove all the things in the profile path.it works for me

Comment: Note that, you need to sign in again.

Answer (score 1):

I got the error when creating a new driver while there was still running an existing driver.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it through manually run `chrome.exe --user-data-dir="userdata folder path"`.
see this [github link](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver/issues/743)